# Getting error while converting json to c#/proto

Tags: c#, asp.net, protocol-buffers, proto

I am trying to convert my Json file data back to proto and c# object.
I added a proto file and built it and it auto generated my cs file from proto file.
So, I have a Json now which I serialized. Now, I want to read that json and cnvert it back to my proto file and c# object.

But I get an error saying

```
 JsonParser jsonParser1 = new(JsonParser.Settings.Default);
 MessageDescriptor messageBuilder = MyProtoClass.Descriptor;
 _ = jsonParser1.Parse("myJsonFileData", messageBuilder);
```

Here the error happens at the last line

```
'jsonParser1.Parse("myJsonFileData", messageBuilder)' threw an exception of type 'Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in C# in the passed, but doing Java mostly now. When programming C# I found that comparing C# and Java was always helpful to me.  I think you'd want a builder at this line, not a descriptor:

```
MessageDescriptor messageBuilder = MyProtoClass.Descriptor;
```

Here's a snippet of Java for going from json to ProtoBuf that I know works.

```
 Builder builder2 = SimpleMessage.newBuilder();
 JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(json, builder2);
 System.out.println("Simple=" + builder2.build());
```